# Sort 2 arrays/vectors based off 1 vector

Tags: matlab

I have 2 arrays (vectors? in `m` vernacular?) and I want to sort them in unison. How can I achieve this in Matlab?

For example; I have found the peaks from a histogram and they are stored in 2 arrays; `peakXVals`, `peakYVals`. They will always be arranged in ascending x axis index. So they will always look like:

```
peakXVals = [0, 3, 20, 77, 240];
peakYVals = [10, 999, 30, 40, 20];
```

I wish to sort both arrays based of the values in `peakYVals` in descending order. Ie from largest peak to smallest peak. So the desired result is:

```
peakXVals = [3, 77, 20, 240, 0];
peakYVals = [999, 40, 30, 20, 10];
```

What function's can I use to achieve this in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sort`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
peakXVals = [0, 3, 20, 77, 240];
peakYVals = [10, 999, 30, 40, 20];

>> [B,I] = sort(peakYVals, 'descend')

B =

   999    40    30    20    10


I =

     2     4     3     5     1
```

Then:

```
>> peakXVals_sorted = peakXVals(I)

peakXVals_sorted =

     3    77    20   240     0

>> peakYVals_sorted = B

peakYVals_sorted =

   999    40    30    20    10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange the two vectors as columns of a matrix and sort the rows of that matrix as atoms, in lexicographical order. Then the results are the columns of the sorted matrix:

```
tmp = sortrows([peakYVals(:) peakXVals(:)], 'descend');
peakYVals = tmp(:,1).';
peakXVals = tmp(:,2).';
```